# Must I add ">&2" in the end of echo command?

Tags: shell

For example

```
#!/bin/bash
INT=-5
if [[ "$INT" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "INT is an integer."
else
    echo "INT is not an integer." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

When I delete ">&2". There is nothing different. Why do I need to add ">&2"

Comment: If the message is not your programs main output, it should go to stderr.

Comment: Related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is:

```
echo "INT is an integer."
```

writes to standard-out, and

```
echo "INT is not an integer." >&2
```

writes to standard-error.

In Unix-world, `stdout` is generally used when everything is working correctly and `stderr` is generally used to print messages when something goes wrong.

By default, `stdout` and `stderr` both print to your screen. The main difference is that the `>` and `|` operators catch `stdout` by default, but not `stderr`.

So if you had your script in the middle of a pipeline, `INT is an integer.` would continue down the pipeline and `INT is not an integer` would print to your screen instead of going into the pipeline.

Comment: Your answer is very clear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That string merges standard out into standard error. You do that and you want to see the output on standard error. Not sure why you would think that would be necessary.

Comment: In an ideal world, all programmers send their error messages to stderr so users can decide to hide or log them independently from regular messages. Sadly, such a world does not exist, and with most languages, many developers simply assume this is an *unecessary habit*.